# Should I award a bounty to a potentially correct answer?

Tags: discussion, bounties, best-practices

This is more of a moral question. I've asked a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871751/cant-ssh-even-with-public-key-added-to-authorized-keys). I ended up solving with my own solution. However, there is 100 bounty points still up in the air and I'm debating whether to give it to one of the answerers who took the time to give a good, well-thought answer which may help others.

Is it ok to give bounty to a good answer, even though I solved it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what I'd do - "One of these answers is exemplary" is a perfectly good reason to give someone a bounty.

It could help others, encourage someone to post more great answers, and build the community as a whole.

As far as the spirit of a bounty goes, that's the right option. You got attention, they posted answers, and one of them is clearly helpful.

Go for it.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is "Would you mark the answer as accepted?" The bounty going to an answer will give future readers a strong indication that it can provide aid in solving a problem like the one described in the question.

Sure you solved the problem on your own, but the trail you leave behind is for those poor saps who come here later with problems similar to your own. So long as the integrity of the bounty is maintained I think you're in the clear.

Also, just so you know how it plays out if you neglect to award it to someone:
https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
>   amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible
>   answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer
>   is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is
>   awarded to anyone.